# How to set up authentication on Purview to ADF?

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-purview

I just connected Azure Data Factory to my Purview account for the first time, the connection is working but seems like it's different from other data sources.

[image]

Also I can see is connected from my ADF:

[image]

How can I setup the authentication and start the scan? I read on the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connect-data-factory-to-azure-purview#set-up-authentication) that I might need to grant the data factory's managed identity Data Curator role on your Microsoft Purview root collection, but I didn't understand how.

Can someone do a step-by-step?

Comment: As per the image you are connecting to purview account successfully, then no need to add role to ADF managed identity, once try what you want to scan?

Comment: I would like to scan all DataFlows and activies available in my ADF account, which has a lot of it.

Answer (score 0):

Connect the Azure account to thedata factoy by clicking on Connect to Purview account

[image]

Select the Purview account

[image]

It will connect automatically without any authentication to the data factory

[image]

You can scan all the data flows in ADF

[image]

Go to purview account and click on browse asset

[image]

Select data factory as source type:

[image]

You can find all activities of data factory there.
example:

[image]

Comment: There is still lack of understanding of which access I should give and where. Because I still cannot see Data Factory under my Purview account.

Comment: You can find your connected data factory at Manage->Data factory in MS Purview account like [this](https://i.imgur.com/9oPbwfB.png).

Comment: Yeah, it's connected like yours. But I mean, I cannot see `Data Factory` under `Browse Assets` in MS Purview portal. Is there any authentication that needs to be done? It mentions something [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connect-data-factory-to-azure-purview#set-up-authentication), but I couldn't figured out how.

Comment: No, no authentication is needed, while connecting to MS purview to Data Factory it connects automatically and add roles to purview account by default without doing anything from our side.